# Spring REST Controller does not route to the desired JSP

Tags: spring

I am trying to redirect to a specific JSP from a Spring REST controller. It works and takes me to the required JSP when I call this service from SOAPUI or any tool to test the service.

In the application I don't see this redirecting to the required JSP though it calls the service and prints the sysout

Can someone guide me

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/authenticateUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView authenticateUser(@RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

Comment: Please paste in the `viewResolver` configuration. Do you want to `redirect:home` or show the view named as `home.jsp`. Please specify this clearly!

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>   I just need to take the user to the home.jsp from the login.jsp through the service.

Comment: And the home.jsp page plz., sorry for spamming!
What do you mean by `it calls the service and prints the sysout`?

Comment: It has got nothing <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/cosmetics/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/cosmetics/js/LoginController.js"/>" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
 Home Page  
</h1>
<h2>Under Constructionsssss</h2> 
</body>
</html>

Comment: What do you mean by it calls the service and prints the sysout? It means I am saying that the service was called properly but I am not sure about the redirection to the home.jsp.

Comment: 1. Add this to your jsp page as the 1st line: `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`

2. Make sure the `home.jsp` is under `/WEB-INF/views/`

3. Clean the project, clean the work directory of server like tomcat

4. Run the application again

Comment: Are you sending your request for the page as a POST?   You can not do a standard link to it since that would be a GET call.

Comment: @BikramKundu - I tried the same and don't see any difference

Comment: @BrianC - Yes I am trying with POST. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Should I capture the response of my service in my JS and route it to the desired JSP or HTML?